# Discord - I'm trying to split a message using discord.js v13.1

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm trying to split a message when it exceeds 2000 characters, but after i update discord.js to 13.1 i can't do it anymore

```js
message.channel.send(code, { split: true, code: "js" })
```

what i tried

```js
message.channel.send({
            content: Util.splitMessage(code)
            })
// let {Util} = require("discord.js")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to pass a char as *splitter* in the [`SplitOptions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/SplitOptions).

> Splits a string into multiple chunks at a designated character that do
> not exceed a specific length.
> ([`Util.splitMessage()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Util?scrollTo=s-splitMessage))

Honestly I find it a little weird how the method is designed. Although the char where the string should be splitted is necessary in order to make it work, the `char` parameter itself is *optional*. And it's even weirder that you don't get the error when sending a message > 2000 chars but actually when using the *Util*-method.

```js
const {
  Util: { splitMessage },
} = require("discord.js");
const split = splitMessage("test".repeat(255) + "x" + "test".repeat(250), {
  char: "x",
}); // => ["test"*255, the other 255 "test"]
```

I suppose you're seeking for a way to automatically shorten a message when it exceeds the limit of `2000` characters.
I'm afraid you'll have to start building your own helper functions in the future for that kind of stuff.

> This functionality will now have to be handled manually, such as via the Formatters.codeBlock and Util.splitMessage helpers.

[Sending messages, embeds, files, etc.](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#customizable-manager-caches)

Luckily it's pretty straight forward:

```
const customSplitMessage = (text) => [
  text.substring(0, 2000),
  text.substring(2000, text.length),
];
```

And then use it like so:

```
message.channel.send({
  content: customSplitMessage("test".repeat(501))[0],
}); // => sends the first exactly 2000 chars
```